# Disable mipmaps for BGE?

Tags: texturing, game-engine

Is there a way to reliably disable mipmapping in the file itself, so that blenderplayer will respect the setting and not interpolate textures?

And no, I'm not making a Minecraft clone.

Answer (score 3):

Mipmaps is a system setting, it would be set by the users startup blend file. Not sure that anyone would recommend overriding a users choice.

To change it you would use python to set `bpy.context.user_preferences.system.use_mipmaps`

Comment: The root reason is that I want to disable texture interpolation. Is there a way to do that in the BGE?

Comment: Actually interpolation is an option for textures in blender render but it is disabled when the game engine is selected. You could try setting `use_interpolation` for a texture but it may be ignored in the game engine.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to mipmap settings, you can change in user preferences > systems > mipmap

But this only work inside blender.

In game (standalone) you need a script.

```
from bge import render
render.setMipmapping(0)
```

related: [Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.render.html?highlight=mipmap#bge.render.setMipmapping)